# If there's no ADC and DAC in SerDes, how come the signal that passes through the channel are analog signals?

Tags: serial

On the Tx side and the Rx side, the signals are digital. And the way we determine whether a SerDes is good or not is to check its eye-diagram, which means there's no analog signal appearing in the SerDes. But how come the signals that passes through the channel are analog signals?

Comment: "the way we determine whether a SerDes is good or not is to check its eye-diagram, which means there's no analog signal"  On the contrary, we check the eye diagram **because** the analog properties of the signal are important. If it was purely a digital signal we could use only a timing diagram (with only 1 and 0 levels on the vertical axis).

Answer (score 3):

"Digital" is just an interpretation of an analog signal, all signals are analog.

With slow signals and/or good transmission channels, the interpretation is simple, and a simple transistor on the input of the receiver can accurately restore the information even if there is some signal degradation on the way.

SERDES itself is mostly about bringing the data to the transceiver -- ten parallel bits go in, and the SERDES block sends out single bits at ten times the speed of the input, so a 300 MHz FPGA can feed a 3 GHz link.

The transceiver will send the bits from the SERDES in a way that they have the greatest chance of arriving at the other end: with a controlled source impedance that can be expected to match the line impedance, and with slight nonlinearities in the output amplifier that improve signal quality at the other end even if it technically degrades it on the sender side -- what is important is the receiver side.

The receiver also has a high speed capable comparator that can keep up with the bitrate, and the output of that is going to be close to the supply rails again, so the interpretation as digital data becomes easier again, and this goes into a deserializer block that outputs ten parallel bits at a slow rate so it's useful for the rest of the logic.

Comment: "all signals are analog":  If you keep this concept in mind, it will improve your PCB designs.  

Also: a comparator can be thought of as a 1-bit ADC.  The trick is to sample the output at the right time.  

There are SERDES implementations that use multiple levels (PAM-4, for example), where there is an ADC of some sort in the receive path.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I now can see that I've been taking digital signal too serious. But I still don't know why the signal in the channel is analog. Is it because the signals serialized contains much imperfections?

Comment: Another way to think of it: a digital signal is an analog signal which obeys the axioms of digital design: discernible logic levels (don't have to be binary, but most often are!), transmitters that support some fan-out number, receivers with some fan-in, and specified propagation delay through a gate (in terms of however many ways it responds) or interconnect.

Answer (score 1):

> *But how come the signals that passes through the channel are analog
> signals?*

A "digital signal" is another name for an idealized analogue signal that is used specifically for digital communication. In other words, it doesn't exist in reality as a proper signal. Once you attach real-world attributes to it, it's effectively an analogue signal.

> *On the Tx side and the Rx side, the signals are digital.*

The bottom line is that they are subject to real-world delays, attenuation, re-shaping due to capacitance, ringing due to inductance and all things that analogue signals are susceptible to. "Digital signal" is an ideality.

If it's on a wire or PCB interconnect it's effectively an analogue signal that we can choose to call digital if we want to.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply! So you mean when the signal enter the Rx side or the Tx, it's exactly analog signal but in an ideal situation, we choose to call it digital?

Comment: It's analogue inside the chip that produces it really but, we just choose to call it digital. Really, digital is just a subset of analogue @yuanyuanyang